# Can airplane mode turn itself off automatically

Tags: networking, mobile-network, airplane-mode

If I have a phone with airplane mode turned on, can it turn itself off automatically (without user interaction)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Airplane mode will stay on as long as you don't set it to turn off on its own.

Comment: Yes there is an app called Tasker which is able to set your airplane mode and WiFi on and off automatically according to time or location. This app requires some getting used to, but the settings you are looking for are pretty simple to set up.

Comment: @A bochur I'm worried about it turning off without me knowing, so unless I installed an app it's impossible

Comment: Correct as long as you didn't install an app that will turn it off, your airplane mode will always stay on.

Comment: This answer is not true.

Answer (score 1):

A [forced system update](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/203023/can-airplane-mode-be-maintained-during-a-system-update), for example, will apparently disable airplane mode.
This can happen without user interaction.
However, such automatic deactivation of Airplane Mode for a system update would generally require the user activating WiFi (after entering Airplane Mode) or some other communication channel that allows the phone to become aware of the requirement for an update.

Also, some apps can activate and deactivate Airplane Mode, if permission is granted.  This is especially true for older (<4.2) versions of Android.